# Problem with fraction sizing in large brackets in alignment mode

Tags: formatting, size

I'm struggling with the sizing of the fractions when placed in alignment mode.

This code here accurately displays what I want the thing to look like:

```
$\left[ \frac{2}{5} u^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^4$
```

However, when placed in the align environment, clearly the fractions are too big for the u variable.

```
\begin{align}
I & = \displaystyle\int_1^4 (u-1)\sqrt{u} \, du \nonumber \\
& = \displaystyle\int_1^4 \left(u^{\frac{3}{2}}-u^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \, du \nonumber \\
& = \left[ \frac{2}{5} u^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^4 \nonmuber
\end{align}
```

I'm new to LaTeX and am just struggling with the basic formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\tfrac`, if you prefer. Here's an example with both ways.

Note it's not necessary to use `\displaystyle`, because it's automatically selected in `align`; also you can use `align*` if you want no line numbered.

I removed `\left` and `\right` where wrong (in the second line).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
I & = \int_1^4 (u-1)\sqrt{u} \, du \\
& = \int_1^4 (u^{\frac{3}{2}}-u^{\frac{1}{2}}) \, du \\
& = \left[ \frac{2}{5} u^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^4
\\
& = \left[ \tfrac{2}{5} u^{\frac{5}{2}} - \tfrac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `\displaystyle` the fractions have always that size. If you do not like it use the `\textstyle`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
I & = \int_1^4 (u-1)\sqrt{u} \, du  \\
  & = \int_1^4 \left(u^{\frac{3}{2}}-u^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \, du  \\
  & = \left[ \textstyle\frac{2}{5} u^{\frac{5}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_1^4 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]